# Why is there a comment box under a deleted answer?

Tags: discussion

I deleted an answer. There was still a comment box under it and I felt like typing into it. However, I could not add the comment because the answer was deleted (by myself).

The comment is not important. But this makes me wonder: why is there this text box that I can type in, but never submit its content?

Maybe make text boxes that cannot be submitted invisible.
I know this is a minor thing, but I would like to know if I'm missing something here.

Comment: If you refresh that tab (or duplicate it), can you still see the box?  Can you still enter text into it?

Comment: Was this off of a refresh? Most of the time you will see a "Comments cannot be added to locked/deleted posts" message where "Add Comment" usually is.

Comment: It seems like the entire question got deleted, cannot find it, not even url from browser history works =(

Answer (score 3):

Moderators can posts comments on deleted posts.

The owner of the post still gets notified of the comment (and can see the post) so it's a nice way of contacting the user privately to send some guidance without sending them a mod message as mod messages should be reserved for serious issues.

It would probably be harder to make the comment box invisible to everyone but moderators than block the comment if you're not.

Comment: But for example your post is not editable for me, because you are a moderator (I assume). If the website has to figure out what buttons I'm allowed to click anyway, I don't quite understand why it's hard(er) to make the text box invisible. The logic is already in place.